# Parameter mismatch in DLL procedure using delphi

Tags: delphi, dll, parameters

I am working with Delphi 2007 and with DLLs and I have programmed a procedure that uses as parameter an integer and a String. I load the dll dynamically in a program in order to test it and printing the parameters on screen as the first instruction of the procedure. The passed values are 0 for the integer and "" for the string but when printing them they become something like 14532 and a trash string. I am aware that I have to use a concrete string type for dll calling and I can fix it but the case of the integer seems pretty mysterious for me. Any idea?

I do not have access to the code right now but I'll try to reproduce it:

My procedure is something like

```
procedure proc(Code: integer; cod: String);stdcall;
begin;
     showmessage(inttostr(code)+ " "+cod);
end;
```

And the other side is:

```
type
call: TCall(Code: integer; cod:String)
handler: THandler
end
....
....
procedure onClickEvent(...)
begin;
handler := loadlibrary(.../library.dll);
if handler <> 0 then
begin
    @call := getprocaddress(handler, "proc");
    if call <> nil then
         call(0,"");
end
freelibrary(handler)
end
```

Comment: You must not use string. Not for interop. What does the other side of the interface look like?

Comment: I edited to add more. As I told I am writing it by memory and it may be a bit different. I always do it the same way when loading a dll.

Comment: It's pointless making it up and posting fake code. Don't do that. Post the actual code. And stop using string. -1

Comment: Alright. I know it but I do not have the original code. I was just trying to get orientation about where the problem might be and then try to solve it by myself. Thanks by the way for your time.

Comment: You need to know what's on the other side. This question is pointless without that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: the code you posted cannot be your real code. It would not
>   compile. Please only post code copied and pasted directly from your
>   editor. Do not retype it or make it up.

As the comments say, don't use `string`. This is a Delphi-specific type, and it is not even always the same. Other languages will not know how to use it. Use `PWideChar` or `PAnsiChar`, depending on what your needs are.

Also, your declaration of `Call` is wrong (you *must* declare it as `stdcall`, since then, parameters will be passed on the stack. If you forget that, parameters will be passed in registers, but the DLL expects them on the stack):

```
type
  TCall = procedure(Code: Integer; Cod: PWideChar) stdcall;

var
  Call: TCall;
```

Implementation in the DLL:

```
procedure proc(Code: integer; Cod: PWideChar); stdcall;
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Code)+ " " + Cod);
end;
```

Now you can call it like:

```
MyString := 'Hello';
Call(0, PWideChar(MyString));
```

Comment: I am totally sure I have not write the stdcall in the declaration. I will try and confirm you if that is the problem. Also thanks for the String example because I have just started with Delphi and I am not really able yet to find examples of it.

Comment: Given that the code doesn't remotely compile, and isn't the real code, we can only guess as to whether or not there's a calling convention mismatch. This question really should be fixed or deleted.

Comment: The fact he gets weird results, even for the integer, makes me think it was really a calling convention mismatch. But you are right, it is not sure.

Comment: Calling convention. Or parameter mismatch. Who can say. Asker needs to learn to stop making things up.

Comment: @David: please see my addition (blockquote) at the top.

Comment: The problem was the stdcall missing in the declaration. My problem was that I cannot get the code from the computer and also cannot access the internet from there. Thanks for the answer @RudyVelthuis

Answer (score 0):

Use PChar inside dll, not string.
More information in http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_DLLs

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of the string problem but I did not knew the correct type yet.